# Join Mysql Doctrine Symfony 3

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

[image]

I have 4 tables and i'm trying make one search on database and get all, without success.

I need show one Menu Food like:

> 1. Hamburguer ( categoriaMenu)
>   - Big Mac ( ProdutoMenu )
>   - Whooper ( ProdutoMenu)
>     1. Sauce ( SubcategoriaMenu)
>       - Chili  (SubprodutoMenu)
>       - Jalapenos (subprodutoMenu)
>     1. Hamburguer Extra (subcategoriaMenu)
>       - cow (subprodutoMenu)
>       - chicken (subprodutoMenu)
> 2. Drinks ( CategoriaMenu)
>   1. Juice ( SubcategoriaMenu)
>     - Orange  (SubprodutoMenu)
>     - Pineapple (subprodutoMenu)
>   1. Soda ( SubcategoriaMenu)
>     - Coca  (SubprodutoMenu)
>     - Water (subprodutoMenu)

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQuery(
                'SELECT cat.nome,p.descricao, p.valor, p.informacoes, s, sp
                      FROM AppBundle:Categoria cat
                      LEFT JOIN AppBundle:Produto p WITH (p.categoria = cat.id AND p.ativo=\'1\')
                      LEFT JOIN AppBundle:Subcategoria s WITH (s.categoria = cat.id AND s.ativo=\'1\')
                      LEFT JOIN AppBundle:Subproduto sp WITH (sp.subcategoria = s.id AND cat.id = sp.subcategoria AND  sp.ativo=\'1\')

                       WHERE cat.ativo =\'1\'');
```

Every start with Categoria,branch to produto(maybe) or directly to subcategoria, and subcategoria branch to subproduto. For a while, i do;

- Search all categorias

> {% for categoria in categorias %}
>                               
>                                   {{ categoria.descricao }}
>                                   
>                               
>                           {% endfor %}

When user click on categoria, the jquery get data from another page, pass as parameter the categoria_id.

That way i'm loosing very time, because each click do another search on database.

Comment: It is difficult to judge what exactly the bottleneck is from the information provided here, but maybe you could reconsider the whole query involving 4 table is really necessary for every click. In some cases you might need to select only a few columns from 1 or 2 tables. Another thing to consider is use the native query instead of the doctrine query: Sometimes doctrine takes every columns in the actual query regardless of necessity.

Comment: Thks, i understood your point. I will try get information of two and two, avoid one query per click on database. Categorias - Produto and Subcategorias-Subprodutos and in twig i make a check between Categorias-Subcategorias.